# Is there a formula to count how many times multiplication is used in cell?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have in Google Sheets (or Excel) a cell with a content `=2*34+3*39`

I need to sum up all the numbers used before the multiplication, in this example it would be `5` (2+3).

Is there any formula in Google Sheets or Excel to do this work?

There are hundreds of different formulas, but I can't find any suitable.

[image: example]

[image: example]

Comment: why 5? can you explain? I see 2

Comment: @player0 I see 2 also, but co-incidentally (and I'm not saying that this is mathematically sound) 2+3 = 5.

Comment: Sorry, Indeed it was impossible to understand what I wanted, I made it now hopefully more clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This will take an assumption, that the formula only use + for each mulification:

```
=sum(query(arrayformula(split(transpose(split(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A38), "=", ""), "+")), "*")), "select Col1"))
```

And this with an assumption, that the formula use + and each has multification:

```
=sum(arrayformula(value(regexextract(transpose(split(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A38), "=", ""), "+")), "^(.*)[*]"))))
```

Answer (score -1):

sure:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(FORMULATEXT(A1); "[^*]"; ))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(1*IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(
 FORMULATEXT(A1); "(\*)"; "$1♥"); "♥"); "(\d+)\*"); 0)))
```

[image: 0]